# iPhone XML post to web service - some GUIDs showing up as Asian characters

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, encoding

A partner on the other end of a web service is saying that some IDs we are sending for tracking are showing up incorrectly.  Here is a normal one and 2 corrupted ones from the same XML doc they sent over to us:

```
<pageID>1e7baddf-1d5f-47bc-ab0f-83a9393e189e</pageID>
<pageID>齎ﺹ鲈｝≊扚Წ</pageID>
<pageID>᜗乯・뤙Ṝ괨Ⅻ㋼</pageID>
```

Any idea why this would happen?  It's only very rarely and I do not know what the characters are supposed to be but it should be in the format of the first item.

I have tried

```
 [NSMutableString stringWithString:
[self stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

and

```
[(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
NULL, (CFStringRef)self, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] ",
kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease]
```

and they claim it's still happening.

Comment: How are you sending the data? The pageID as posted doesn't really need to have URLEscaping - I don't think that that is the issue. If you haven't converted the string to an NSData object with something like [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; that might be an issue.

Comment: self would just be a class inheriting from NSString.  I didn't start this project, I took it over from someone else, their string class has some utility functions.

Comment: Good question John, I didn't even think to look at that and assumed the encoding was at fault, I just assumed it posted.  It's sending via a query string, url below is https://<fullurl>.asmx?xml=<..allthexmlhere..>

  NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
  [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

Answer (score 1):

your pageID seems like HEX numbers, and it's not only asian chars but some arabic fonts as well.

1. Try to print the actual string which is being sent over to the web service just before they leave the function. So I suppose if you are using `NSURLConnection` then check before you send the data.
2. If the data which is being sent is the desired then it is not your fault but the fault is inside the web services's deserialize method.

Comment: I was thinking it was a decoding issue on their end as well.  There are thousands+ page ids and this happens maybe .01% of the time, I have not been able to replicate this behavior.  I guess I could write a loop to parse all the data and pull all the pages IDs and log them.